Stable Koszul complex depends only on the radical
In the following paper:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.02473
in Appendix A, the following definitions are given:

for an element $\alpha$ of a commutative Noetherian ring $R$, the stable Koszul complex is a chain complex $K^\bullet_\infty(\alpha)$ defined as
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> R @>>>R[\frac{1}{\alpha}]@>>>0
\end{CD}
$$
with the middle arrow given as canonical map into localization.
for a sequence of elements $\underline{\alpha}=(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ the complex $K^\bullet_\infty(\underline{\alpha})$ is defined as $K^\bullet_\infty(\alpha_1)\otimes_R\ldots\otimes_R K^\bullet_\infty(\alpha_n)$.

There is also a statement that a stable Koszul complex of an ideal $I=(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ (defined as a stable Koszul complex of a sequence of generating elements) depends, up to quasi-isomorphism, only on the radical of $I$. How to prove it?
An idea I tried is the following: there is also a statement that if $\beta$ is in the ideal $I=(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$, then $K^\bullet_\infty(\underline{\alpha})[\frac{1}{\beta}]$ is exact. I thought I can use this idea to define a map of two Koszul complexes and show that the cone of this map is exact. However, I am not sure if I know how to define this map in general.
